# Using the verb "crack a joke" transitively

Tags: usage

Based on dictionary definition [here](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/crack_1)(#10) I know that the word "cracK" is a transitive verb, hence I should be able to make a sentence like the one bellow:

> - He is a very funny guy. He cracks **us** a hundred jokes a day.

Unfortunately, I didn't find even a single example on the internet where this verb has been used transitively.

I need to know how a native would say my self-made sentence?

Comment: He is not cracking *us*; *us* is not a direct object here. Compare *He bakes us 100 pies a day.* The direct object is *100 pies*.

Answer (score 3):

"crack a joke" is an idiomatic expression. The verb "crack" is still transitive in this case; the object of crack is "a joke".

Your sentence would best be expressed as

> He cracks a hundred jokes a day for us

Comment: It would be the same in the present.

Answer (score 0):

My answer would be anecdotal and without a proper grammatical founding, but I would say "He cracks a hundred jokes a day" leaving out the pronoun "us" as implied.